# Convert a tensorflow script to pytorch (TransformedDistribution)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, distribution, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to rewrite a tensorflow script in pytorch. I have a problem finding the equivalent part in `torch` for the following line from [this script](https://github.com/progrmanial/Google-AI-Research/blob/8da9f60982aefdc020cfcf25292d8c2a8eda60ed/behavior_regularized_offline_rl/brac/networks.py#L77):

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions
a_distribution = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
        distribution=tfd.Normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0),
        bijector=tfp.bijectors.Chain([
            tfp.bijectors.AffineScalar(shift=self._means,
                                       scale=self._mags),
            tfp.bijectors.Tanh(),
            tfp.bijectors.AffineScalar(shift=mean, scale=std),
        ]),
        event_shape=[mean.shape[-1]],
        batch_shape=[mean.shape[0]])
```

In particular, I have a huge problem for replacing the `tfp.bijectors.Chain` component.
I wrote the following lines in `torch`, but I am wondering whether these lines in pytorch compatible with the above `tensorflow` code and whether I can specify the `batch_shape` somewhere?

```
base_distribution = torch.normal(0.0, 1.0)
transforms = torch.distributions.transforms.ComposeTransform([torch.distributions.transforms.AffineTransform(loc=self._action_means, scale=self._action_mag, event_dim=mean.shape[-1]), torch.nn.Tanh(),torch.distributions.transforms.AffineTransform(loc=mean, scale=std, event_dim=mean.shape[-1])])
a_distribution = torch.distributions.transformed_distribution.TransformedDistribution(base_distribution, transforms)
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pytorch, the base distribution class [`Distribution`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.distribution.Distribution) expects both a `batch_shape` and a  `event_shape` parameter. Now notice that the subclass [`TransformedDistribution`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.transformed_distribution.TransformedDistribution) does not take such parameters ([*src code*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributions/transformed_distribution.py#L46)). That's because they are inferred from the base distribution class provided on initialization: see [*here*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributions/transformed_distribution.py#L57) and [*here*](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/distributions/transformed_distribution.py#L78-L79).

You already found out about [`AffineTransform`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html?highlight=affinetransform#torch.distributions.transforms.AffineTransform) and [`ComposeTransform`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html?highlight=composetransform#torch.distributions.transforms.ComposeTransform). Keep in mind you must stick with classes from the [`torch.distributions`](https://torch.distributions).

- This holds for [`torch.normal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.normal.html) which should be replaced with [`Normal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#normal). With this class, the shape is inferred from the provided `loc` and `scale` tensors.
- And [`nn.Tanh`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Tanh.html) which should be replaced with [`TanhTransform`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#torch.distributions.transforms.TanhTransform).

---

Here is a minimal example using your transformation pipeline:

###### Imports:

```
from torch.distributions.normal import Normal
from torch.distributions import transforms as tT
from torch.distributions.transformed_distribution import TransformedDistribution
```

###### Parameters:

```
mean = torch.rand(2,2)
std = 1
_action_means, _action_mag = 0, 1
event_dim=mean.shape[-1]
```

###### Distribution definition:

```
a_distribution = TransformedDistribution(
    base_distribution=Normal(loc=torch.full_like(mean, 0), 
                             scale=torch.full_like(mean, 1)), 
    transforms=tT.ComposeTransform([
        tT.AffineTransform(loc=_action_means, scale=_action_mag, event_dim=event_dim), 
        tT.TanhTransform(),
        tT.AffineTransform(loc=mean, scale=std, event_dim=event_dim)]))
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. Just a quick question, would you elaborate the reason for this choice `torch.full_like` and its components inside `Normal(loc=torch.full_like(mean, 0),  scale=torch.full_like(mean, 1))` distribution?

Comment: The base distribution must needs to have a shape with size at least equal to the `event_dim`, Initializing `Normal` with a 2D `loc` and `scale` allows to sample from independent gaussian, in the case above a 2d vector.